# Magento 2 Argument of preference constructor is also a preference, error

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection

I'm overriding class `Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerRegistry` with my own preference. Then I create a preference for `Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface`, which has an argument in the constructor of type `CustomerRegistry`.

This is part of my `di.xml`:

```
<preference for="Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerRegistry"
                type="Tmo\Customer\Model\CustomerRegistryPreference" />
<preference for="Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface"
            type="Tmo\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepositoryPreference" />
```

Besides, Interceptor class created by Magento2 Dependency Injection is there with the proper argument of type `CustomerRegistryPreference`, however I'm getting the next error:

```
Recoverable Error: 
Argument 3 passed to Tmo\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepositoryPreference\Interceptor::__construct() 
must be an instance of Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerRegistry, 
instance of Tmo\Customer\Model\CustomerRegistryPreference given, 
called in /src/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 181 and 
defined in /src/var/generation/Tmo/Customer/Model/ResourceModel/CustomerRepositoryPreference/Interceptor.php on line 12
```

I was expecting from Magento the correct dependency injection but I got that error. 
Even if I delete the preference for `Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface`, I get the same error but in the core class:

```
Recoverable Error: 
Argument 3 passed to Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository\Interceptor::__construct() 
must be an instance of Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerRegistry, 
instance of Tmo\Customer\Model\CustomerRegistryPreference given, 
called in /src/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 164 and 
defined in /src/var/generation/Magento/Customer/Model/ResourceModel/CustomerRepository/Interceptor.php on line 12
```

If I modify the class `CustomerRepositoryPreference` in the constructor changing the argument `CustomerRegistry` for `CustomerRegistryPreference`, the problem is solved, but in the second example when the preference was gone, I shouldn't modify the core class.

So my question is if there is a way to fix this error without touching the argument in the constructor???

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. I explain it:
I'm using preferences because I need to use or change the protected methods or attributes of core classes, so my preferences were a copy of those core classes.

Instead of being an **exact copy** or the original, the preferences which **doesn't implements** an interface, now **extends** from the core files and the problem is solved.

Example, before:

```
class CustomerRegistryPreference
{ }
```

Example, after:

```
class CustomerRegistryPreference extends \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerRegistry
{ }
```

Example, implementing an interface:

```
class CustomerRepositoryPreference implements \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface
{ }
```

Happy ending :)